# Can someone tell what is wrong with my code.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, response

Onclick listener is making my app crash. When I comment it out, it runs fine.
In XML I just have an edit box and a button.I am also extracting the text entered by getText().toString(), is it correct.

```
public class PnrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String m_PNR,pnr;
final String pnr_url="https://";
final String api_key="";
final String apiFunction ="";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pnr);
    Log.d("Rail","PNR");
    Button enterButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.PNR_Button);
    EditText enterPNR=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterPNR);
    Log.d("Rail","PNR");
    m_PNR=enterPNR.getText().toString();
    Log.d("Rail","PNR:"+m_PNR);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("Rail","onclick");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: You want to get edit-text input data at the same time of input?

Comment: I am making api call using the input and want to show the details got from api call.

Comment: you request using user input and retrieve details belong to that input...your problem is show the details under the input??@NamanKumar

Comment: Thing is, I want to get input from the user in edit text and when he enters the details, I want to display the details which I am getting from the api call in the same layout, below the edit text box. Means when the user comes to this screen he will only see the edit box to enter details and when hi presses enter , the details should appear below that. I don't want to create different layout for that.

Comment: as answer below your TextView.setText("your detailes from any where user or api")..is fit your needs??/@NamanKumar

Comment: Thanks, My doubt was about visibility of the textview. After user input I will make the visibility from gone to visible.

Comment: Can some one tell me what is wrong with my code. Onclick listener is making my app crash. when I comment it out, app runs.

Answer (score 0):

use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) or a button to show information in a textview which is placed below your edittext

Comment: I am making api call using the input and want to show the details got from api call.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to display the same text which is inputted after some events (like click,touch etc), Simply use,

```
String x="your api call response";
textview.setText(x);
textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

If you want to display the text while typing, Use `TextWatcher`

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          textview.setText(s.toString());
    }
};
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

In the same XML, have all the views.

Comment: I am making api call using the input and want to show the details got from api call.

Answer (score 0):

As you said "I am making api call using the input and want to show the details got from api call."

Then you have to make your API call and parse the response and set values to your fields using `editText.setText("value from your response");`

If you have any problem parsing your response please add some code to your question.

**Please Write this if you have visibility issues :**

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thing is, I want to get input from the user in edit text and when he enters the details, I want to display the details which I am getting from the api call in the same layout, below the edit text box. Means when the user comes to this screen he will only see the edit box to enter details and when hi presses enter the details should appear below that. I don't want to create different layout for that. I don't have any problem in parsing the response.

Comment: You mean to say if you enter Naman in edit text the value coming from response should be written below your edittext? or naman should get replaced with new value?

Comment: What will be there in response? is there any validation message or something like that?

Comment: @NamanKumar as you said *when he presses enter ,the details should appear below that.* . I think you have to have textview below edittext with visibility gone. after the api call, Set the result to textview and make it visible

Comment: Okay. That's what my problem was. Didn't know that we can set visibility. Thanks mate!! Thank you all.@Developer.    One confusion I will have to set the visibility of text view  in java file, right?  Can you please tell me the syntax for that?

Comment: Check my Updated answer!! Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks Deep. Got it. @DeepPatel

Comment: WC mate! Do the needful please ;)

Comment: HI @DeepPatel, I have edited my question. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: What is the crash information shown in Logcat? Have you checked that? Please add that here as well. It will be helpful to resolve ur issue

Comment: Code seems to be Okay but if you post your logcat details we can dig into that